# jquery autocomplete from mysql

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I have a question with a autocomplete function in jquery-ui. I've

```
var availableTags = [ "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp"];
```

that i want to get from a mysql-table with thousands of records.

```
$( "#find" ).autocomplete({ source: availableTags });
```

like

```
$( "#find" ).autocomplete({ source: availableTags }, $('#find').value());
```

??

How to put the autocomplete that, it sents a search phrace before receiving the availableTags. I don't want to mine whole table after every key pressing. Too high complexity.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the basic JQuery you can take a look at the  example 
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote  at the remoteDatasource example

you can see:

```
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
            source: "search.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
            }
        });
```

minlenght is the minimum letter that you can input to make the research starting.

On the server side you have to create something like

```
//connect to your database

$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));//retrieve the search term that autocomplete sends only when there are 2 char or more

$qstring = "SELECT description as value,id FROM test WHERE description LIKE '%".$term."%'"; //ONLY AN EXAMPLE
$result = mysql_query($qstring);//query the database for entries containing the term

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))//loop through the retrieved values
{
        $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['value']));
        $row['id']=(int)$row['id'];
        $row_set[] = $row;//build an array
}
echo json_encode($row_set);//format the array into json data
```

You need to uotput something like this JSON if you are not on crossdomain(on cross domain you need JSONP but this is another story )

```
[{"value":"Some Name","id":1},{"value":"Some Othername","id":2}]
```

---

WORST PRACTICE
Another solution (but is not logically ok) is to create the entire JS array with a loop on recordset, generating a string like.

var availableTags = [ "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp",...];

so you have your table hardcoded and immutable in the page but each data are exposed in the source of the page it's only to learnin purpose but never do this in production.

---

If you wont to mine the table in alternative mode you need to specify how you wont, but autocomplete is  based on 2 ideas.
1) Each keyperss help to make a better restriction so on each keypress there is the need to do another query

2)When new key is pressed the last result is not important so last request is abandoned.

So in on some condition you can yuse a dinamic limit in your query when  there are few keys typed, you can limit result to a limited amount of record, when the typed sequence grow you can remo the limi or limit to a big number of recor because the were condition makes it's job better.

---

I hope to be useful

Answer (score 0):

You will want to make a call to a web service that goes and does the finding for you. Then you can leverage whatever features your server side language / ORM or whatever has for making the search process efficient.